# How can I change the size/design of the navigation arrows in Product Gallery Slider plugin?

Tags: css, navigation

I have installed the Product Gallery Slider for Woo Commerce plugin in the Astra theme, and it works well except the navigation arrows do not show up on dark images.  Ideally I would like to have the arrow change from black to white, depending on the background color.  I have my windows curser set up to do this and it works well.
If this can't be done, perhaps I can use an arrow with a background color that will make it stand out.

I checked with the developer and he said that this could be done with custom CSS but I have no idea how to write the code.  There is a place in the plugin for custom CSS but I don't know what to put there.

Please look at the following page to see what I mean about the arrows not showing up on the dark background:
https://uniquebabyquiltboutique.com/product/duck-pond-baby-quilt/

It shows up on the light backgrounds, but even so I would like to make it bolder